# Phantom js doesn't support Arrow function ( => )

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lambda, jasmine, phantomjs

I am working on unit testing of Angular app using Jasmine.
Everything was working fine on the Chrome until i started using PhantomJs for the headless browser testing or test output on the console.

After 2 days, I found that PhantomJs doesn't support lambda expression.
There isn't any problem with the unit tests but it was with lambda expression and PhantomJs.

I am using -

1. AngularJs - 1.6.6
2. Jasmine - 2.9.1
3. PhantomJs - 2.1.1

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The proper JavaScript term for them is "arrow functions" (they aren't just lambda expressions).

Comment: Accepted. Do you know the answer ?

Comment: I didn't, but a trivial search turned it up and I'd already posted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PhantomJs [doesn't support arrow functions yet](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#phantom). In fact, it supports very little of ES2015. See this comment from pixiuPL (the maintainer) from [this issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15287) in their repo:

> Introducing ECMA will require nearly-complete rewrite and - keeping in m8ind I seem to be the only active dev of PJS now - will need to wait till other - more urgent - issues are solved.
>
> In the meantime, if you feel skilled enough - feel free to start working on it, but on the separate branch.

Answer (score 3):

Use function expressions instead. Add `bind` if you want to capture the `this` value.

e.g.

Change:

```
(foo, bar) => this.example(bar, foo);
```

to

```
(function (foo, bar) { return this.example(bar, foo); }).bind(this)
```

Comment: Yeah Quentin. This will work. I want know why part and Mr Crowder answered me Why the arrow function won't work. By the way, Thanks.

Comment: It would have helped if your question had included an actual question :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Babel to transform the arrow function:

babel.config.json

```
{ "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions"
  ]
}
```

From the command line:

```
babel infile.js --out-dir out --config-file babel.config.json
```